# Command substitute compound command in string

Tags: bash

```
arg1=$(printf win && printf 32)
echo $arg1
contents='printf win && printf 32'
arg1=$($contents)
echo $arg1
arg1=$( { eval $contents; } )
echo $arg1
```

The results are:

```
win32
win
win32
```

Why doesn't the `$($contents)` work? One would presume that command substitution works by inserting the stdout of the declared command...?

Furthermore when `contents='echo win && echo 32'` it returns `win && echo 32`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because parameter substitution happens after logical operators parsing.

Bash doesn't know there is an `&&`, so `printf win && printf 32` is interpreted as below:

```
argv[0]: printf
argv[1]: win
argv[2]: &&
argv[3]: printf
argv[4]: 32
```

printf ignores all the arguments starting with argv[2], because argv[1] contains no format strings.

Comment: @MetaChrome: "Parameter substitution" refers to things like replacing `$contents` with its value. There's no way to execute a compound command from a variable without `eval` (which tends to cause other problems). See [BashFAQ #50:I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Also: what problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I'm not solving any particular problem, as I am aware, as specified how to accomplish the same thing functionally with eval. I am trying to get a better grasp of the caveats and tricks of bash. That link was very useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's figured out what is going on using `set -x`:

```
set -x

arg1=$(printf win && printf 32)
echo $arg1

contents='printf win & printf 32'
arg1=$($contents)
echo $arg1

arg1=$( { eval $contents; } )
echo $arg1

set +x
```

```
++ printf win
++ printf 32
+ arg1=win32
+ echo win32
win32
+ contents='printf win && printf 32'
++ printf win '&&' printf 32
+ arg1=win
+ echo win
win
++ eval printf win '&&' printf 32
+++ printf win
+++ printf 32
+ arg1=win32
+ echo win32
win32
+ set +x
```

The most important part here is

```
+ contents='printf win && printf 32'
++ printf win '&&' printf 32
```

This is how command substitution perform word splitting and evaluating what is a command here and what is a command arguments. So it evaluates not as 2 separate commands but as 1 command `printf` with 4 arguments, which equals to `win`.